# SQL Comparing a table attribute from values from other table

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to compare values from the first table **InputStrings** with values in the second table **StringConstraints** in Sql.

**InputStrings**

```
+-----------+------------+-----------+
|   Name    |  Address   |   City    |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
| abcabcabc | xyxyxyxy   | qweqweqwe |
| abbcabc   | xyxxyxy    | qweqwe    |
| abccabc   | xyxyxyxyxy | qwweqwe   |
+-----------+------------+-----------+
```

**StringConstraints**

```
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| colName | minlength | maxlength |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
| Name    |         2 |        20 |
| Address |         4 |        10 |
| City    |         5 |        10 |
+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want to check if the length of the values in the *Name* column is between 2 and 20; length of values in the *Address* column is between 4 and 10; and length of values in the *City* column is between 5 and 10.

There are 68 rows like this in my table. InputString has 40 columns in it. I can't write for each and every row.

Can anyone help me make a generalized solution to compare the values?

*I'm new to the database area.*

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: Tagged with `oracle` after the comment in the duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48535946/330315

Answer (score 0):

this will return bad records:

```
Select *
from InputStrings
where (len(Name) not between (select minlength from StringContraints where colName = 'Name')
   and
       (select maxlength from StringContraints where colName = 'Name'))
   or
      (len(Address) not between (select minlength from StringContraints where colName = 'Address')
   and
       (select maxlength from StringContraints where colName = 'Address'))
   or
      (len(City) not between (select minlength from StringContraints where colName = 'City')
   and
       (select maxlength from StringContraints where colName = 'City'))
```

Comment: what if there are about 40 columns in InputString ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to create the same thing dynamically. Please keep in mind that Stack Overflow is not a coding service.

```
declare @sql varchar(max) =''
    ,@Name varchar(50)
    ,@min int
    ,@max int
    ,@counter int =1;


declare csr cursor
for
select colName, minlength, [maxlength] from (values ('Name',2,20),('Address',4,10),('City',5,10)) a(colName,minlength,[maxlength])

open csr

fetch next from csr
into @Name,@min,@max

set @sql = 'select * from inputstrings where '

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if(@counter =1 ) set @sql = @sql + '(len('+ @name+') not between ' + cast(@min as varchar(5)) + ' and ' + cast(@max as varchar(5)) + ') '
    else set @sql = @sql + 'or (len('+ @name+') not between ' + cast(@min as varchar(5)) + ' and ' + cast(@max as varchar(5)) + ') '

    set @counter=@counter +1

    fetch next from csr
    into @Name,@min,@max
end

close csr
deallocate csr

print @sql

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: I needed the values part in declaring cursor because i don't have your tables. replace that with StringConstraints

Answer (score 0):

You didn't state your DMBS, so this is a solution for Postgres:

```
select *
from (
  select i.id, 
         t.*,
         c.minlength, 
         c.maxlength,
         length(t.value) between c.minlength and c.maxlength as is_valid
  from inputstrings i
    cross join lateral jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(i) - 'id') as t(colname, value)
    join stringconstraints c on lower(c.colname) = lower(t.colname)
) t
where not is_valid
order by id;
```

This first turns each row from the table `inputstrings` into key/value pairs and the result of that is joined to the `stringconstraints` table. From there it's easy to validate the column values based on the constraints. This is independent of the number of columns in `inputstrings`. The result will be one row per column value that violates the constraints.

For the following setup:

```
create table inputstrings (id integer, name text, address text, city text);
insert into inputstrings
values
(1, 'Name OK','Some Address that is too long','City Name OK'),
(2, 'N', 'Address OK', 'Cty'),
(3, 'Good Name', 'Good Address', 'Good City');

create table stringconstraints (colname text, minlength int, maxlength int);
insert into stringconstraints
values
('Name', 2, 20),
('Address', 4, 12),
('City', 5, 15);
```

The query returns this result:

```
id | colname | value                         | minlength | maxlength | is_valid
---+---------+-------------------------------+-----------+-----------+---------
 1 | address | Some Address that is too long |         4 |        12 | false   
 2 | name    | N                             |         2 |        20 | false   
 2 | city    | Cty                           |         5 |        15 | false
```

I added the `id` column so that it is possible to match a invalid column value to the actual source row.

Online example: http://rextester.com/VVG55773

Second example with more columns: http://rextester.com/QCKG53573 (note the query hasn't changed)